# Configuring the Zsh prompt/Inserting custom characters without external commands

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, zsh

I like making my own prompts. And, I want them to be simple and to be written in the $PS1 and $PS2 variables only. I don't want them to be separate files, or whole scripts or programs, and I also want them to run as little external programs as possible
So, that brings me to the reason I'm posting this

This is the current way I configure my prompt:

```bsh
function setPromptTheme()
{
    if [ $UID = 0 ]
      then _promptColorUID=yellow
      else _promptColorUID=blue
    fi # Checks if the user is root and colors some parts of the prompt accordingly

    if [ -z $SSH_CONNECTION ]
      then _promptColorSSH=white
      else _promptColorSSH=yellow
    fi # Checks if the session is running through SSH and colors some parts of the prompt accordingly

    export PS1="%(?.%K{green}%F{black} √ %F{green}%K{black}$(printf '\ue0b0')%f%k.%K{red}%F{black} × %F{red}%K{black}$(printf '\ue0b0')%f%k)%K{black} %F{$_promptColorSSH}%n@%M %F{black}%K{$_promptColorUID}$(printf '\ue0b0')%k%K{$_promptColorUID}%F{black} > %k%F{$_promptColorUID}$(printf '\ue0b0')%f%k "
    export RPS1="%F{$_promptColorUID}$(printf '\ue0b2')%K{$_promptColorUID}%F{black}  %(5~|%-2~/…/%2~|%4~) %F{black}%K{$_promptColorUID} $(printf '\ue0b2') %f%k%K{black}%F{white}  %h %f%k"
}
```

So, my problem is that I have to run printf to insert Powerline characters, and I don't want that since it slows things down, of course

Is there any way to insert custom characters in the prompt without the usage of an external command? And optionally, does anyone have a way of making this even faster if there is any?

Note: Also, this `\['\ue0b2'\]` didn't work for me, I've tried, or maybe I've done it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$'\uxxxx' or $'\Uxxxxxxxx'` here (while the `$'...'` quotes come from ksh93, the interpretation of `\u`/`\U` in there was actually introduced by `zsh`, and copied by a few other shells since, though with variations).

So:

```
PS1="...."$'\ue0b2'"...."
```

Or:

```
myChar=$'\ue0b2'
PS1="...$myChar..."
```

or

```
typeset -A powerline=(
  branch        $'\uE0A0'
  ln            $'\uE0A1'
  padlock       $'\uE0A2'
  'solid right' $'\uE0B0'
  right         $'\uE0B1'
  'solid left'  $'\uE0B2'
  left          $'\uE0B3'
)
```

and use `$poweline[solid right]` for instance.

`\[` and `\]` is *bash* syntax to introduce 0-width data.

The `zsh` equivalent would be `%{...%}`, but here, those characters have a  width of one column, so you *don't* want to use that. On my system at least characters in the *private use area* (as used by powerline here) have a width of 1 already (according to `wcwidth()` used by zsh to determine the width of characters). If `wcwidth()` returned 0 for those, you could always insert a `%G` to tell zsh they have width 1.

Comment: That actually worked, thank you! Also, I've used the variable method you've shown there